# Passing in a sort callback to d3.sort

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, d3.js

I have a selection like this -

```
@thead.append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(@columns)
    .enter()
    .append("th")
    .text((col)-> return col)
    .on("click",(d)=>@rows.selectAll("tr").sort(@strAsc))
```

where strAsc is some function like this

```
    strAsc:(x,y)->
    console.log "strAsc being called"
    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0))
```

However, the console.log never runs when I click on the th. Why?

Comment: Don't you want to sort the `th` tag instead of the `tr`?

Comment: no, I'm clicking on the th because I want to sort the rows based on the values of the cells under that column

Comment: I can't say w/o seeing more code, but most likely `@rows` is a selection of `tr` elements, so `@rows.selectAll("tr")` (a subselection) is an empty set.